# How to define the WebPluginMIMETypesFilename in the plist of a safari webplugin project?

Tags: cocoa

I want to know the defination of WebPluginMIMETypesFilename, if my project is SafariPlugins. target extension is webplugin, My WebPluginMIMETypesFilename is com.SafariPlugIns.webplugin.plist? and what is the webPluginMIMETYpes, I just know when safari lunch , it will test the webplugin if have the webPluginMIMETYpes or not. and then load the plugin , but it is what to do ? and it's definition?

and another question is : if I define the the Principal class of plist my plugin class name:SafariPlugIn, and if the App will begin in that class firstly. and in the plugin class the method:

- (NSView *)plugInViewWithArguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments

will begin firstly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know the defination of WebPluginMIMETypesFilename …

It's the name of the file in which you've declared the MIME types your plug-in can handle. You'll add that file as a resource of the plug-in.

> it is what to do ? and it's definition?

According to [Chromium's WebKit source](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/webkit/glue/plugins/plugin_lib_mac.mm?view=markup), the contents of the file should be a dictionary with the key `WebPluginMIMETypes`, whose value should be another dictionary. Presumably, that inner dictionary should be of the same format that you might put directly into your Info.plist file, as exemplified by [ClickToFlash's dictionary](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-01-29/how-clicktoflash-works).

> and another question …

Should go in another question.