# How to register a document MIME type on OSX so it appears in browsers navigator.MIMETypes array

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, mime-types

Is there a way to have my application's document MIME types (declared in my info.plist) show up in my browser's navigator.mimeTypes array?

On windows, you register your MIME type in the registry, and it shows up in Firefox's mimeType array, but I can't seem to do the equivalent thing in OSX.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to edit it on your computer, then you could try [moreInternet](http://www.monkeyfood.com/software/moreInternet/).

If you are installing an app, and also want it to put stuff in Safari on install, you could provide a Safari plug-in or xxtension; which you can learn about in the [Safari Extensions Development Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [WebKit Plug-In Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/WebKitPluginTopics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001247-SW1). Also see [How to define the WebPluginMIMETypesFilename in the plist of a safari webplugin project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1476249/2291) that links to some examples of info.plist file syntax.